# Error while inserting into array of timestamps

Tags: postgresql, insert, timestamp, array

Im using postgres 10.1 and the Datestyle config is the following

```
 DateStyle
 -----------
 ISO, MDY
```

Im having this error

> ERROR: date/time field value out of range: "1535673858" Hint: Perhaps
>   you need a different "datestyle" setting.

While executing the following insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO ex (taken_ats) VALUES('{ 1535673858 , 1535678856}')
```

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE ex (
    taken_ats TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE[]
)
```

Comment: `1535673858` is not a "timestamp" - that's a number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`1535673858` is neither in the ISO format, nor in any of the other [valid date input formats](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-DATE-TABLE).

To convert a Unix epoch value into the internal Postgres type, you must use the [single-argument `to_timestamp()` function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TABLE):

```
INSERT INTO ex(taken_ats) VALUES(ARRAY[to_timestamp(1535673858), to_timestamp(1535678856)]);
```